# Serilog doesn't produce a valid json (structured logging)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, serilog

I'm developing an application using asp.net core and Serilog for logging.
I have the following code:

```
Log.Information("Application Starting.");
Log.Information("Message: fetching all Requests");
```

My Serilog config file look like this:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Settings.Configuration" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "System": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
      }
    },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {

                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "..\\Logs\structuredLog.json",
                  "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
                  "fileSizeLimitBytes": 20485760
                }
              }
            ],
            "Enrich": [
              "FromLogContext",
              "WithMachineName",
              "WithProcessId",
              "WithThreadId"
            ],
            "Properties": {
              "ApplicationName": "Serilog.WebApplication"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

The Problem:
As an output i get an invalid JSON file:

```
{"Timestamp":"2021-07-27T10:09:41.9531148+02:00","Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"Application Starting."}
{"Timestamp":"2021-07-27T10:09:46.7538684+02:00","Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"Message: fetching all Requests"}
```

I expect to get something like this:

```
[
   {
      "Timestamp":"2021-07-27T10:09:41.9531148+02:00",
      "Level":"Information",
      "MessageTemplate":"Application Starting."
   },
   {
      "Timestamp":"2021-07-27T10:09:46.7538684+02:00",
      "Level":"Information",
      "MessageTemplate":"Message: fetching all Requests"
   }
]
```

Can someone please help me to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I generate the json log, I can adjust the format by using the format that comes with vs.

Format shortcut: `Ctrl+K` or `Ctrl+D`.

If it doesn't work, do it like this：

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is an alternative solution to make the JSON file human readable, however the JSON still not valid. I think this kind of JSON called Line-delimited JSON and is produced for streaming purposes. Any way many Thanx for your support :)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct with the statement that the JSON file is not a valid JSON object. In the context of a logging library the output should not be seen as a file but a stream of data. So each log entry is one item in a possibly never ending flow.

This is also why it makes no sense to add an opening array indicator and adding comma after each line.